# How to scroll an image on top of another using 3d matrix

Tags: javascript, css, image, css-transforms

Im trying to recreate this effect from apple.com (its the third section): https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-4k/

And this is how far ive come: https://scrolleffekt.webflow.io

However, I have no clue how to make the image overlap each other like they do on Apples website. Here is an image from their site for reference: [Image from Apples site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1IyW.jpg)

I have set the div with the images inside to overflow: hidden and transform-origin: bottom, but I seem to have an issue with 3d matrix and how to make the images stay in the same place.

I hope someone can help.

Here is currently my Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
    const tv = document.querySelector("#tv").getBoundingClientRect()

    const x = document.querySelector("#x")
    const y = document.querySelector("#y")
    const z = document.querySelector("#z")
    const m = document.querySelector("#m")

    const b = document.querySelector("#b").getBoundingClientRect()
    const c = document.querySelector("#c").getBoundingClientRect()
    const d = document.querySelector("#d").getBoundingClientRect()

    {
        const diff = b.top - tv.bottom
        x.style.transform = `matrix(1,0,0,1,0,${Math.min(0, diff)})`
    }
    {
        const diff = c.top - tv.bottom
        y.style.transform = `matrix(1,0,0,1,0,${Math.min(0, diff)})`
    }
    {
        const diff = d.top - tv.bottom
        z.style.transform = `matrix(1,0,0,1,0,${Math.min(0, diff)})`
    }
})
```